# UWP install SQL Server Express or other pre requisites

Tags: c#, sql-server, uwp

Is there a way to install pre requisites from an UWP app published in the store?
I want to develop several multi user UWP apps that use SQL Server.

First I was trying to get all SQL server instances within a network to be able to select one if present, or give the option to install a server if none exists. Seems that UWP cannot use any existing method to get those instances:

- SqlDataSourceEnumerator is not present in net core
- SqlClientFactory.CanCreateDataSourceEnumerator is always false
- SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServer also throws exceptions and cannot be used from UWP, as seems that it also uses SqlDataSourceEnumerator

Then I was trying to use Process from System.Diagnostics to start a cmd, use "net view" to get all workgroup computers, and then, by powershell or cmd, get services running on those computers to check if sql express exists. But, Process cannot be used from UWP apps, always throws access denied (even with "runas", that cannot be used as it needs Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute, that trows a "platform" error). I was hoping to use cmd or powershell to download and install SQL Server too. When I was using winforms I installed it even from the setup (using innosetup)

So, as long as you can connect to almost any type of database server from UWP, how can we use the store to deliver apps that need any pre requisite?

Comment: There is no way to install pre requistes from an UWP app published in the store for security requirements. Almostly, all UWP apps run in a sandbox, which limits a UWP app to get instances of other softwares. The usage of Process in UWP apps is restricted for security requirements, so you cannot use “net view” to get all workgroup computers to check if SQL Server Express exists.

Comment: Yep, many drawbacks in benefit of security. So, one solution in those scenarios is to guide the user through all the "post install" process. Or get rid of local network databases solutions.